# Can I modify the exit key for the less command in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, terminal, less

Is there any way to customize the less command to exit using a key other than 'q'?

### EDIT

I have tried creating a file called `lesskey` under `$HOME/.config` with the following contents:

```
#command
\b quit
```

to quit with the backspace key, as [man lesskey](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lesskey.1.html) indicates.

Comment: see: "KEY BINDINGS" under `man less`.  (and/or `man lesskey`)

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it by writing this to file:

```
#command
\177 quit
```

and then doing `lesskey <file>`